# .so patch version differences between RedHat and Ubuntu

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

I have built a .so on Ubuntu that requires `libssl.so` (it wants `libssl.so.1.0.0`).

The actual version of libssl.so that is installed is `libssl.so.1.0.2k`, but there is a link `libssl.so.1.0.0` to that file, so I imagine that Ubuntu handles patch versions by just replacing them with `.0`.

If I try to use that .so on RHEL7, it fails to find it. My RHEL7 system also has `libssl.so.1.0.2k` installed, but the link to it is named `libssl.so.10`. I surmise that RHEL handles the patch versions by discarding them and jamming the major and minor versions together.

I tried to resolve by creating a link named `libssl.so.1.0.0` to `libssl.so.1.0.2k`. Did the same thing for `libcrypto.so.1.0.0` to `libcrypto.so.1.0.2k`. Now I get something weird:

```
% ldd libironoxide_java.so 
./libironoxide_java.so: /lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: version `OPENSSL_1.0.0' not found (required by ./libironoxide_java.so)
./libironoxide_java.so: /lib64/libssl.so.1.0.0: version `OPENSSL_1.0.0' not found (required by ./libironoxide_java.so)
./libironoxide_java.so: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.18' not found (required by ./libironoxide_java.so)
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffcfda70000)
    libssl.so.1.0.0 => /lib64/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0x00007fc82d0d2000)
    libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007fc82cc70000)
    ...
```

But the `libssl.so.1.0.0` that it found does NOT require `OPENSSL_1.0.0`

```
% objdump -p libssl.so.1.0.0 | grep SSL
3 0x00 0x066a2b21 OPENSSL_1.0.1
4 0x00 0x02b21533 OPENSSL_1.0.1_EC
5 0x00 0x066a2b22 OPENSSL_1.0.2
    OPENSSL_1.0.1 
    0x02b21533 0x00 08 OPENSSL_1.0.1_EC
```

I can't find any other instances of `libssl.so.1.0.0` on the system that should be confusing things.

Any idea what is happening here? And any suggestions for building a `.so` that will work on both Ubuntu and RHEL7?

Comment: Ubuntu and Red Hat are fundamentally different systems. You should build separate packages for (1) Debian and derivatives; and (2) Red Hat and derivatives. Also see *"How does the versioning scheme work?"* and *"What is special about OpenSSL on Redhat?"* in the [OpenSSL FAQ](https://www.openssl.org/docs/faq.html).

Comment: Version numbering is a weak point of OpenSSL, so different distributors came up with different fixes. Hopefully version 3 will fix this (a few year ahead methink).

Answer (score 0):

RedHat is widely known for modding the kernel and libraries extensively. It is virtually impossible to adapt a critical library as OpenSSL to ensure compatibility with Debian-based systems.